# Kendo UI, datagrid, how to get properties object?

Tags: properties, kendo-grid

I would like to get datagrid properties (name of visible columns, pinned columns, etc).

Is it possible in Kendo and if yes how can i do it?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        for (var i = 0; i < grid.columns.length; i++) {

            console.log(grid.columns[i]);

        }
```